# on android, does the Documents Path will always be /data/data/mypackagename/files/?

Tags: android, delphi

and android, does the Documents Path (`Tpath.GetDocumentsPath` on Delphi) will always be `/data/data/mypackagename/files/`? and from inside a java unit, how can I retrieve the Documents Path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the [Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath), on Android, `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` returns [`Context.getFilesDir()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29). That page says:

> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to
>   an adopted storage device

So, no, the path might not always be the same (not to mention it might also change in a future version of Android).